# Can I override a type parmeterized method with concrete type in scala?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, traits

I want to override a type-parameterized method by assigning a concrete type to the type-parameter, something like the code below.

```
trait A {
  def amethod[T](x: T): T
}
trait B extends A {
  def amethod(x: String): String = x ++ x
}
```

However the compiler gives `amethod overrides nothing`. I cannot put `[String]` after `amethod` in trait B, as syntactically it means a type parameter named String not the type java.lang.String. I am wondering whether and how I can do something like that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have control over trait `A`? If so, you could make it take `T` as a type parameter, and make `B` a subtype of `A[String]`.

Comment: No. `B` breaks its contract with `A`.

Comment: this works perfectly for me.. can you explain what is the issue?
`trait A { def amethod[T](x: T): T };
trait B extends A { def amethod[String](x: String) = x };
class C extends B {};
val c= new C();
c.amethod("Hello");
res5: String = Hello`

Comment: @rogue-one Try calling `c.amethod(1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`amethod`, as it's defined in trait `A`, is a generic method, meaning that each call can be applied to generic arguments.

What you are trying to say in trait `B` is to change the scope at which generality is expressed, moving it from the call site to the class definition itself. It's not possible to do it.

As it's been suggested in a comment, if you want to express generality in a class definition, the type parameter should be applied to the class, not to the method:

```
 trait A[T] {
   def amethod(x: T): T
 }

 trait B extends A[String] {
   override def amethod(x: String): String = x ++ x
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As an explanation of the comment saying "`B` breaks its contract with `A`", consider this code:

```
def foo(): A = new B {} // legal because B extends A
def bar = foo().amethod[Int](0)
```

What should happen? If you are tempted to say that it should be rejected by looking at the body of `foo`, imagine it's an abstract method instead, and some class happens to implement it in this way.